# Having trouble adding TStringLists with chunks

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I am trying to separate data coming from a dataset (Q) into chunks of 10 and place them into a `TStringList`.

I've create a `TStringList` called `LIST`, where every time a record is found it adds a value (UID).

I have tried to use an array of `TStringList`s to keep track, but it's just a bit cumbersome.

The idea would be, for example, given a dataset that delivers 24 records, `LIST` can have the first 10 values in `LIST.strings[0]`, records 10 to 20 in `LIST.Strings[1]`, and records 21,22 and 23 in `LIST.Strings[2]`.

Any ideas or directions you might think of? I've tried counters also, and it's just not happening. Should I deal with `LIST` afterwards?

```
const chunks = 10
List := TStringList.Create;   
Q.Open;
try
  While not Q.EOF Do
  begin
    UID := Q.FieldByname('U_ID');
    List.Add(UID.AsString);
    Q.Next;
  end;
  Q.Close;
finally
  FreeAndNil(Q);
end;
//SO DESIRED OUTPUT SOMETHING LIKE THIS  
//LIST.COUNT =3
//LIST.STRINGS[0] = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  
//LIST.STRINGS[1] = 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 
//LIST.STRINGS[2] = 21,22,23
```

I have also tried to use `Insert()`, like this:

```
List.QuoteChar := ' ';
if List.Count <= 10 then
begin
  MaxList.Insert(0, List.DelimitedText);
end;
if ((List.Count > 10) and (List.Count <= 20)) then
begin
  MaxList.Insert(1, List.DelimitedText);
```

But `Insert()` index doesn't work as I want it.

Comment: its mess of a loop, dont bother showing you..its hard for me to keep track after 10 records have been inserted since if i useList.DelimitedText will take it from the first record..so just if any suggestions where to go..i'll appreciate.

Comment: You are aware that the LIST.Clear will render your code rather pointless?

Comment: yes, had it there becuase i was using another tstringlist..you right gone now

Comment: The data structure you are proposing (chunks of 10) looks really strange. Why do you need it? I smell an X-Y problem here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your goal is to store the UIDs as comma-separated strings, where each string holds up to 10 UIDs max. If so, try something like this:

```
const
  chunks = 10;

var
  List: TStringList;
  counter: Integer;
begin
  ...
  counter := 0;
  List := TStringList.Create;   
  try
    Q.Open;
    try
      if not Q.EOF then
      begin
        UID := Q.FieldByName('U_ID');
        repeat
          if (counter mod chunks) = 0 then
            List.Add(UID.AsString)
          else
            List.Strings[List.Count-1] := List.Strings[List.Count-1] + ',' + UID.AsString;
          Inc(counter);
          Q.Next;
        until Q.EOF;
      end;
    finally
      Q.Close;
    end;
    // use List as needed...
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use 2 `TStringList`s instead of a counter, eg:

```
const
  chunks = 10;

var
  List: TStringList;
  Chunk: TStringList;
begin
  ...
  List := TStringList.Create;   
  try
    Q.Open;
    try
      if not Q.EOF then
      begin
        UID := Q.FieldByName('U_ID');
        Chunk := TStringList.Create;   
        try
          repeat
            if Chunk.Count = chunks then
            begin
              List.Add(Chunk.CommaText);
              Chunk.Clear;
            end;
            Chunk.Add(UID.AsString);
            Q.Next;
          until Q.EOF;
          if Chunk.Count > 0 then
            List.Add(Chunk.CommaText);
        finally
          Chunk.Free;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Q.Close;
    end;
    // use List as needed...
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach with a helper string list:

```
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Q.Open;
    try
      line := TStringList.Create;
      try
        cnt := chunks;
        While not Q.EOF Do
        begin
          Dec(cnt);
          if cnt = 0 then begin
            List.Add(line.CommaText);
            line.Clear;
            cnt := chunks;
          end;
          UID := Q.FieldByname('U_ID');
          line.Add(UID.AsString);
          Q.Next;
        end;
        if line.Count > 0 then
          List.Add(line.CommaText);
      finally
        line.Free;
      end;
      Q.Close;
    finally
      Q.Free;
    end;
    // SO DESIRED OUTPUT SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    // LIST.COUNT =3
    Assert(List.Count = 3);
    // LIST.STRINGS[0] = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    Assert(List[0] = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10');
    // LIST.STRINGS[1] = 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
    Assert(List[1] = '11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20');
    // LIST.STRINGS[2] = 21,22,23
    Assert(List[2] = '21,22,23');
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
```